# How does AMCL publishes tf using pose?

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-kinetic, tf2, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my project, I am able to obtain a special pose (a future pose based on prediction) of a robot, and I need to publish the pose as tf from `map` to `odom_future` frame (my new frame). I know that amcl has provided such a tf publishing code. Therefore, I try to use the AMCL code to write a publisher that convert a pose and publish tf like amcl. However, I encountered some difficulties.

In the amcl_node.cpp file, it contains the following lines:

```
    // subtracting base to odom from map to base and send map to odom instead
    geometry_msgs::PoseStamped odom_to_map;
    ...
    tf2::Quaternion q;
    q.setRPY(0, 0, hyps[max_weight_hyp].pf_pose_mean.v[2]);
    tf2::Transform tmp_tf(q, tf2::Vector3(hyps[max_weight_hyp].pf_pose_mean.v[0],
                                          hyps[max_weight_hyp].pf_pose_mean.v[1],
                                          0.0));

    geometry_msgs::PoseStamped tmp_tf_stamped;
    tmp_tf_stamped.header.frame_id = base_frame_id_;
    tmp_tf_stamped.header.stamp = laser_scan->header.stamp;
    tf2::toMsg(tmp_tf.inverse(), tmp_tf_stamped.pose);  //invert the given pose
    this->tf_->transform(tmp_tf_stamped, odom_to_map, odom_frame_id_); ///subtraction occurs here
    ...
```

I tried to use this snippet to help build my tf broadcaster, but it gives the error:

```
"Do not call canTransform or lookupTransform with a timeout unless you are using another thread for populating data. Without a dedicated thread it will always timeout.  If you have a seperate thread servicing tf messages, call setUsingDedicatedThread(true) on your Buffer instance.";
```

My only major modification is the time stamp, because my node does not subscribe a laser scan (I also tried to subscribe a laser scan, and use the timestamp, but it doesn't work as well):

```
tmp_tf_stamped.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
```

I've also tried `setUsingDedicatedThread(true)`. The error disappears, but the node doesn't do anything.

Questions:

1. What exactly does `tf_->transform(...)` do? I couldn't find any documentation about this function.
2. Does the error originated from the timestamp?
3. Is there any other elegant way to compute the tf between `map` and `odom_future` from pose? (in the same way of `odom` frame).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/294925/how-does-amcl-publishes-tf-using-pose?/) by [alex_f224](https://answers.ros.org/users/35926/alex_f224/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2018-06-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured out it is non-trivial in my application to compute `tf(map, odom_future)` and `tf(odom_future, base_footprint_future)` given `amcl_pose` using the method used in AMCL.

As shown in the AMCL ROS webpage, it has the following tfs:

`tf(map, odom) + tf(odom, base_footprint) = tf(map, base_footprint)`

`tf(map, odom)` is the drifting effect by the odometer.
`tf(odom, base_footprint)` is the pose of the robot from the odometer reading.

The pose given by AMCL is `tf(map, base_footprint)`. In my application, since I am predicting the future, the `amcl_pose` is in the future. In other words, `tf(map, odom)`, `tf(odom, base_footprint)`, `tf(map,base_footprint)` are in the future, while only `tf(map,base_footprint)` is given by my motion predictor.

One way to overcome this is to build a motion model to predict future robot pose in the `odom` frame, i.e.  `tf(odom, base_footprint)`, which is not a trivial task. One could use the velocity motion model, but it might be a naive solution.

---

Originally posted by [alex_f224](https://answers.ros.org/users/35926/alex_f224/) with karma: 28 on 2018-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1